# How to open a Facebook post to wall from webpage?

Tags: facebook, twitter

I am writing a website and want a user to be able to click post to Facebook and have it open a window already filled out with a custom post. I do not want to have to authenticate them with my site or anything like that just send them to a Facebook url with the post already filled in.

Twitter has something like this that I am using. For instance click this http://twitter.com/home?status=This%20is%20a%20custom%20post

Is there a way to do this same thing for Facebook? If so does anyone know the URL?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution I was looking for. To post to a Facebook wall without actually managing tokens you must make a call to the url below with the parameters specified below.

"http://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=YOU_APP_ID&link=A_LINK_HERE&picture=PATH_TO_A_PICTURE&name=SOME_NAME&caption=SOME_CAPTION&description=SOME_DESCRIPTION&message=MESSAGE_TO_POST_ON_WALL&redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URL_AFTER_POST"

This will redirect back to the url that was specified in redirect parameter after the post. It will have the parameter post_id with the id of the new post or no params if they did not post. You can find documentation here http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/.

Answer (score 0):

The Like and Send buttons provide this functionality:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/
You include meta tags on your page and the Like / Send button pick this up for sharing to a user's wall.

Answer (score 0):

You can't prefill story text, it's against FB policies. Twitter is cool with that, but on Facebook it's a no-no.

See: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/policy/examples_and_explanations/stream_stories/

Scroll down a bit to 'Platform Policy IV.2'

You can put suggestions of what to say on the screen, but you can't prefill the comment box.